# how to detect the center frequency of a QRS complex in an ECG signal?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, noise, signal-detection

i want to design a filter that can effectively detect the QRS complex in ECG signal(whose Fs=360Hz) and reduce high frequency noise components. i want to know as to how the center frequency is detected so as to design a digital lowpass differentiator filter with bandwidth equal to the center frequency of the QRS complex.

Comment: Can you describe the what the QRS complex is?

Comment: The QRS complex is a name for the combination of three of the graphical deflections seen on a typical electrocardiogram (ECG). It is usually the central and most visually obvious part of the tracing.
please check this figure
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SinusRhythmLabels.svg